ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname on a proxy enables system
I want to load the BPEmb model on a machine which is accessbile using proxy only.
Initially, I configured the proxy setting, environment and tried. But it couldn't load the model.
Therefore I downloaded the BPEmb files manually and stored in a folder and gave the path.
However, I still get the error:
downloading https://nlp.h-its.org/bpemb/en/en.wiki.bpe.vs10000.model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ss/ton.py", line 316, in <module>
    processor.stream_process()
  File "/home/ss/ton.py", line 114, in stream_process
    bpemb_en = BPEmb(lang="en", vs=10000, cache_dir='/home/ss/BPEmb')
  File "/home/sd/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bpemb/bpemb.py", line 173, in __init__
    self.model_file = self._load_file(model_file)
  File "/home/sd/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bpemb/bpemb.py", line 228, in _load_file
    return http_get(file_url, cached_file, ignore_tardir=True)
  File "/home/sd/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bpemb/util.py", line 48, in http_get
    headers = http_get_temp(url, temp_file)
  File "/home/sd/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bpemb/util.py", line 23, in http_get_temp
    req = requests.get(url, stream=True, verify=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 544, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 657, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 697, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 971, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 500, in _connect_tls_proxy
    return ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 453, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 495, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1028, in _create
    raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname 

Is it the right way to load model from downloaded files? Or any suggestion to download

There is no code, only a stacktrace from the error. Please see [mcve] for what is expected to get useful help.
